# NSDateFormatter parsing dates 2 seconds behind

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I've tested a few formatters but the results i'm getting are off by 2 seconds, weird.
I've read a few posts on stack overflow but haven't seen anything like this before.

```
func testDates() {

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.systemLocale()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-M-d"
    formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

    let formatter2 = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter2.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter2.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    formatter2.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()


    let tests = ["923-05-17","1700-05-01", "1701-9-9", "1702-9-01", "1703-09-5", "1991-01-05"]
    let dates = tests.map({$0.toDate(formatter)})
    let dates2 = tests.map({$0.toDate(formatter2)})

    println(dates)
}



extension String {
    func toDate(formatter: NSDateFormatter) -> NSDate? {
        return formatter.dateFromString(self)
    }

}
```

results are:

```
Printing description of dates:
([NSDate?]) dates = 6 values {
  [0] = 0923-05-16 23:52:58 PST
  [1] = 1700-04-30 23:52:58 PST
  [2] = 1701-09-08 23:52:58 PST
  [3] = 1702-08-31 23:52:58 PST
  [4] = 1703-09-04 23:52:58 PST
  [5] = 1991-01-05 00:00:00 PST
}
Printing description of dates2:
([NSDate?]) dates2 = 6 values {
  [0] = 0923-05-16 23:52:58 PST
  [1] = 1700-04-30 23:52:58 PST
  [2] = 1701-09-08 23:52:58 PST
  [3] = 1702-08-31 23:52:58 PST
  [4] = 1703-09-04 23:52:58 PST
  [5] = 1991-01-05 00:00:00 PST
}
(lldb)
```

Comment: I don't think you should care about the time if it wasn't part of the original string.

Comment: its not the time that I'm worried about, its the fact that its setting the Day back by shifting the clock back 2 seconds.

Comment: see "1700-05-01" =>  1700-04-30 23:52:58 PST

Comment: btw, you are off by 7 minutes and 2 seconds

Comment: I seem to remember Apple recommending using noon if you "don't care" about the time

Comment: The algorithm used to convert dates assumes that certain corrections to "standard time" were made in the past.  This is not a "bug" but the way it's intended to work.

Answer (score 0):

Appears to be that this is a problem parsing dates before the 20th century :)

```
    var centuries = [String]()
    for x in 0...22 {
        centuries.append("\(x*100)-01-01")
    }
    let centuriesDates = centuries.map({$0.toDate(formatter)})


Printing description of centuries:
([String]) centuries = 23 values {
  [0] = "0-01-01"
  [1] = "100-01-01"
  [2] = "200-01-01"
  [3] = "300-01-01"
  [4] = "400-01-01"
  [5] = "500-01-01"
  [6] = "600-01-01"
  [7] = "700-01-01"
  [8] = "800-01-01"
  [9] = "900-01-01"
  [10] = "1000-01-01"
  [11] = "1100-01-01"
  [12] = "1200-01-01"
  [13] = "1300-01-01"
  [14] = "1400-01-01"
  [15] = "1500-01-01"
  [16] = "1600-01-01"
  [17] = "1700-01-01"
  [18] = "1800-01-01"
  [19] = "1900-01-01"
  [20] = "2000-01-01"
  [21] = "2100-01-01"
  [22] = "2200-01-01"
}
Printing description of centuriesDates:
([NSDate?]) centuriesDates = 23 values {
  [0] = nil
  [1] = 0099-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [2] = 0199-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [3] = 0299-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [4] = 0399-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [5] = 0499-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [6] = 0599-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [7] = 0699-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [8] = 0799-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [9] = 0899-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [10] = 0999-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [11] = 1099-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [12] = 1199-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [13] = 1299-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [14] = 1399-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [15] = 1499-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [16] = 1599-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [17] = 1699-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [18] = 1799-12-31 23:52:58 PST
  [19] = 1900-01-01 00:00:00 PST   <<<< Finally started working
  [20] = 2000-01-01 00:00:00 PST
  [21] = 2100-01-01 00:00:00 PST
  [22] = 2200-01-01 00:00:00 PST
}
(lldb)
```

Comment: i guess so :) @DavidRönnqvist

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist - It's not "undefined behavior" -- It's very well defined.  There are many discontinuities in the "mapping" of UTC to individual timezones.